# After changing the automation tool (maven -> gradle), the application does not build

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I replaced maven with gradle in the project. Previously, the application worked without any problems. Now using the `gradle clean build` command, the application throws a few errors regarding e.g. constructor or logger, nothing like this appeared when using maven. What could be the cause of this and possibly how to fix it?

**Some example of errors:**

```
error: variable itemService not initialized in the default constructor
    private final ItemService itemService;
```

**ItemController**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController("GraphItemController")
@RequestMapping("/api/stats")
public class ItemController {

    private final ItemService itemService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<ItemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTO>> getItemsByCategoryAndTypeStatistic() {
        List<ItemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTO> itemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTOs = itemService
                .getItemsByCategoryAndTypeStatistic();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(itemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTOs, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**ItemServiceImpl** (error relates to logger)

```
error: cannot find symbol
        log.info("Categories reading started");
        ^
  symbol:   variable log
  location: class ItemServiceImpl
```

**ItemServiceImpl**

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service("GraphItemServiceImpl")
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {

    private final ItemRepository itemRepository;
    private final TypeRepository typeRepository;
    private final CurrentUser currentUser;

    @Override
    public List<ItemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTO> getItemsByCategoryAndTypeStatistic() {

        log.info("Categories reading started");
        Map<String, ItemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTO> byCategory = findByCategory();
        Map<String, ItemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTO> byCategoryAndType = findByCategoryAndType();
        log.info("Categories reading completed");

        if(byCategory.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        enterItemsNumberForTypeInRelatedCategoryDTO(byCategoryAndType, byCategory);

        List<ItemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTO> itemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
        itemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTOs.addAll(byCategory.values());

        return itemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTOs;
    }
```

**Or something like this even though the environment does not show anything in red, only when building.**

```
itemByCategoryAndTypePairs.put(itemNumberByCategory.getAppaCategoryName(), itemNumberByCategory);
                                                               ^
  symbol:   method getAppaCategoryName()
  location: variable itemNumberByCategory of type ItemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTO
```

**ItemServiceImpl**

```
private Map<String, ItemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTO> convertListToMap(
            List<ItemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTO> itemsNumberByCategories) {

        Map<String, ItemsByCategoryAndTypeStatisticDTO> itemByCategoryAndTypePairs = new TreeMap<>();
        itemsNumberByCategories.forEach(itemNumberByCategory -> {
            itemByCategoryAndTypePairs.put(itemNumberByCategory.getAppaCategoryName(), itemNumberByCategory);
        });

        return itemByCategoryAndTypePairs;
    }
```

Comment: The issue is not your code, but your migrated build. Show your `build.gradle`.

Comment: check Unicode for java file must be utf8 not utf8bom

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to the migration from Maven to Gradle, it's related to Project Lombok. Enable Project Lombok in your IDE and all the errors should be gone.

You are getting this:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        log.info("Categories reading started");
```

and using the annotation `@Slf4j`